# Batch prediction: "INTERNAL ERROR 500", am I the only one?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, vertex

When I want to do a batch prediction using a trained model with AutoML tables, I obtain this error:

Internal error encountered.

Response code: 500
Status: INTERNAL

Tracking number: XXX

[image: Screenshot]

I have been providing a csv file and I always get this error.
Am I the only one ? How can I solve this problem ? Thank you !

Comment: Please provide more information about your batch, which region, how you are executing this, do you have any duplicated rows,are you using at least 2 feature columns with batch predictions? What kind of data are you using? Does it work if you retry the request? This is full error? Is it possible to provide some part of your batch and all steps to replicate this issue?

Comment: My data is on a cloud storage bucket in the eu-west4 region. I do not have any duplicated rows and I used 17 feature columns. All the columns are categorical. I have tried many times and I always get the same error. I do not get any more information about the error... Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Please share some logs. Could you provide some part of your data to replicate this issue and your steps? Didnt you reach quota?